# Calculating portions of protein And carbs

Tags: measurements, high-protein

I have started a new program and what still confuses me when I hear, 1

> .18 x lbs of body weight Example: 200 lbs x 1.18 = 236 g of lean
>   protein per day

If I am right, it means I need to multiply 1.8 with my body weight (in pounds)? If so then why in example, it says 1.18 and other place .18?

Comment: I wrote a Computer Program for calculating all of this stuff out. Using `BMR and the Harris Benedict Equation` And splitting it all into a `40% protein 40% carb 20% fat diet.` I'm going to assume you don't have python installed. So if you want too give me your details I could input this into the program if you would like? Example [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iw8qi.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iw8qi.png)

Answer (score 1):

As 0.18 grams per pound of body weight is a very small amount, it's probably just a typo. 1.18 makes sense.